# when to alloc and initialize a view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode

recently I joined two Xcode projects together. To get this thing to work, I had to alloc and initialize my view controller.

```
self.myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
```

But why? In the other project I have the same code. The sole difference is hierarchy of the different views. I added a new view to the top (beginning). So the calling View Controller is not the first view on the stack anymore.

I'm pushing my view in this way on the stack:

```
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:myViewController animated:YES];
```

In my NIBs I have added a View Controller object with IB and connected the Outlets.

And I have a memory **management question** too: If I have a property like myViewController, do I have to release it? The "normal" release is done in the dealloc method. But do I have to use an additional release because of the alloc? I don't think so, but I ask you anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would need to see more code to answer why you had to alloc your view controller, but I'd say that you always alloc them manually (at least in my experience).

As for the memory management question, if your property is declared as a `retain` property (`@property(retain) UIViewController *myViewController`), you are indeed leaking memory, since the retain count after alloc will be 1, and after the retain done by your accessor will be 2. Hence, if you release it only once, you'll end up with a leak.

I usually do this instead:

```
self.myViewController = [[[MyViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! There is not anymore code behind. I'm doing it completely with IB because I was confused of using arrayWithObject:viewControllers/pushViewController/addSubView/initWithNibName ... So either releasing it two times or using autorelease?

Answer (score 0):

I found it out: In IB I had to set the nib name on my view controller object. So the alloc and initialization is done by IB?

Answer (score 0):

There is one more option:

```
(IBAction)loginButton:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSLog(@"pressed login");
    ICMasterViewController *controller = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mainnav"];
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

On your storyboard you must have `UIViewController` with name `mainnav`